# Is there any feature in Kusto for network graph plotting?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Is there any function in Kusto for network graph plotting ? Basically I have a dataset of nodes and edges and would like to visualize it -- similar to what lot of other visualization libraries in Python provide? If not already , is it on the cards?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [KqlMagic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kqlmagic) with any Python plotting library you like.

Here's an example of drawing a simple graph using [ipycytoscape](https://github.com/Quantstack/ipycytoscape):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes but the question is about Kusto , processing it on Kusto cluster using Kusto query language. If I have to use Python then of course it has many network visualization libraries such as networkx etc.